# Custom fonts in rrdgraph in a Docker container running Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, docker, fonts, rrdtool, alpine-linux

I'm unable to use other fonts than the standard one in rrdgraph.

It may have to do with the fact, that this Alpine has no GUI (all the X-stuff), I don't know.

I found this issue https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/1475 dealing with missing fonts, but installing those packages doesn't help.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk --update add \
      build-base python-dev \
      ca-certificates python \
      py-pip \
      py-jinja2 \
      py-dateutil \
      py-tz \
      py-requests \
      py-pillow \
      py-rrd && \
    pip install --upgrade arrow \
                          websocket-client \
                          XlsxWriter && \
    apk del build-base python-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    echo "iot"

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

I added those font packages manually later on with a `docker exec -it iot /bin/sh`

I tried stuff like

```
  # rrd_graph_fmt += ["--font", "LEGEND:8:'/home/user/data/fonts/Roboto-Regulars.ttf'"]
  # rrd_graph_fmt += ["--font", "LEGEND:8:font-sony-misc"]
```

but it just doesn't work. I'm not even sure how to change the font globally by using environment variables. I tried (some stuff on the web with the env vars), but it didn't work.

I'd really love to use ttf fonts, but would settle with those in the packages if neccessary.

I'm using the rrdtool lib from the py-rrd package.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRDtool uses fontconfig to access fonts ... to see what fonts are available on your system you can use

```
fc-list
```

to configure where fontconfig should look for fonts, you may want to edit `/etc/fonts/...` or `~/.fonts.conf.d` in your homedirectory.

To refresh the list of fonts, run

```
fc-cache
```

Note that font support is independent of X11.

Comment: Thanks Tobi. If `fc-list` now lists among others `/usr/share/fonts/Type1/c0632bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Bold` -- `/usr/share/fonts/Type1/c0649bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Italic` -- `/usr/share/fonts/Type1/c0633bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Bold Italic` and `/usr/share/fonts/Type1/c0648bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Regular`, how do I then use that font? `["--font", "LEGEND:8:\"Bitstream Charter\""]` and without Quotes does not work.

Comment: Oh, ok, I forgot to restart the container, maybe reloading the py-rrd module would do this as well.